# Load report from file created from Stream in FastReport

Tags: c#, stream, report, fastreport

There is a method that builds reports. It generates stream on server and then save it to a tmp file.

```
public virtual void Build(ReportType reportType, ReportParameters parameters)
{
        Export = reportType.Id == MaterialReportIds.WarehouseBalanceDynamic;

        var tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
        try {
            ServiceManager<IMaterialsReportsDataService>.Invoke(service =>
            {
                using (var stream = service.BuildReport(reportType, parameters)) {
                    using (var fileStream = File.Create(tempFileName)) {
                        int buf;
                        while ((buf = stream.ReadByte()) >= 0) {
                            fileStream.WriteByte((byte)buf);
                        }
                        fileStream.Flush();
                        fileStream.Close();
                        stream.Close();
                    }
                }
            });

            Report.LoadPrepared(tempFileName);
        }
        finally {
            File.Delete(tempFileName);
        }
}
```

On service :

```
public Stream BuildReport(ReportType reportType, ReportParameters parameters) {
        IReport report = new ReportFactory(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).CreateReport(reportType);
        try {
            report.Build(reportType, parameters);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            (report.Object as Stream)?.CopyTo(stream);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return stream;
        } finally {
            (report?.Object as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

After that we use `Report.LoadPrepared(path to a tmp file)` and it works, but when I try to use `Report.Load(path to a tmp file)` it doesn't. Do anybody know why? The error says that file format is incorrect, but why `Report.LoadPrepared()` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing from the documentation FastReport provided [here](https://www.fast-report.com/public_download/FRNetProgrammerManual-en.pdf).

`Load` method accepts ".frx" files:

```
report.Load("report1.frx");
```

From the other hand `LoadPrepared` accepts ".fpx" files:

```
Report.LoadPrepared(this.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Prepared.fpx"));
```